# Как открыть новое окно с использованием QML?

Tags: android, qml, qt

Здравствуйте.

Пишу мобильное приложение на Qt 5.4. Для описания интерфейса взял QML. Возникла следующая задача.
Есть два окна, родительское и дочернее. Соответственно, вызов дочернего окна происходит из родительского.

Требуется вызвать дочернее окно так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки "назад" на ОС Андройд приложение возвращалась к родительскому окну.

При таком вызове дочернего окна кнопка назад выходит из приложения.

```
var component = Qt.createComponent("ChildWnd.qml")
var window    = component.createObject(root)
window.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите пример [Touch Gallery](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols-touch-example.html).

У меня `Window` на Андроиде не работает, работает только `Dialog`. Но там тоже есть проблемы с размещением компонентов. `StackView` оказался лучшим вариантом.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно, в таких случаях дочернему окну передают ссылку на родителя. И дети уже юзают родительские методы show и hide.

Comment: Проблема не в том, что я не передаю ссылку на родителя. Не создается новое Actvity, окно открывается поверх текущего. Я хочу использовать нативную навигацию Анройда.

Answer (score 0):

еще один голос за `StackView`. Сам перепробовал несколько вариантов, в т.ч. `Popup` из `controls 2`, но и он мне не подошёл, хотя очень даже ничего.

Comment: Ваш ответ тянет максимум на комментарий.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению в андроид нельзя открыть "новое" окно, оно одно. Но вы можете заново загрузить старое с другой разметкой, для этого используйте слот в c++, подключенный к qml. Там вызываете приватный слот через

```
QUrl url(str);
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "loadnewurl", Qt::QueuedConnection, Q_ARG(QUrl, url));
```

Уже в этом слоте обращаетесь к QQuickView, если обратится в первом программа упадёт, ибо один поток.

Вы можете использовать мой пример на github, https://github.com/tripolskypetr/qmlloadnewmarkup